# How do I read in data sitting a folder with a quotation in the name?

Tags: r, data.table

So let's say I have a file data.csv that I want to read into R. However, this file is in the path C:/Users/abc/Documents/"My Data's Methods". Notice the quotation after Data. How can I read the CSV in using `fread()`?

Comment: Have you escaped the quotations with a backslash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the whole string in double quotes, `fread("path/My Data's Methods")`.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
data.table::fread('C:/Users/abc/Documents/"My Data\'s Methods"/data.csv')
```